# Fedora 13 post security update boot problem

Tags: boot, grub, kernel, fedora-13

About a month ago I installed a security update that had new Kernek 2.6.34.x from 2.6.33.x), this is when the problem occurred for the first time.

After the install my computer would not boot at all, black screen without any visible hard drive activity (I gave it good 30 minutes on black screen, before took actions)... I poped in installation DVD and went in rescue mode to change back the boot option to old kernel (was just a guess where the problem was). After restart computer loaded just file, took a long time for it to start because of `SELinux targeted policy relabel is required. Relabeling could take very long time depending on file size`. I assumed that the update got messed up somehow and continued working with modified boot option.

Couple of days ago, there was another kernel update. I installed it and same problem as before. This rules out corrupted update theory... Black screen right after 'BIOS' screen before OS gets loaded. I had to rescue system again... Below is copy of my `grub.conf` file. I am fairly new to LINUX (couple of years of experience), mostly development and basic config... nothing crazy.

```
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,0)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_obalyuk-lv_root
#          initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=2
timeout=0

splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Fedora (2.6.34.6-54.fc13.i686.PAE)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.34.6-54.fc13.i686.PAE ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_obalyuk-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_obalyuk/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_obalyuk/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYTABLE=us rhGB quiet
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.34.6-54.fc13.i686.PAE.img
title Fedora (2.6.34.6-47.fc13.i686.PAE)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.34.6-47.fc13.i686.PAE ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_obalyuk-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_obalyuk/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_obalyuk/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYTABLE=us rhGB quiet
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.34.6-47.fc13.i686.PAE.img
title Fedora (2.6.33.8-149.fc13.i686.PAE)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.33.8-149.fc13.i686.PAE ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_obalyuk-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_obalyuk/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_obalyuk/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYTABLE=us rhGB quiet
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.33.8-149.fc13.i686.PAE.img
```

I like my system to be up to date... Let me know if I can post any other files that can be of help.

Has anyone else had this problem? Does anyone has any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've frequently found that Linux kernel updates break various systems and have just given up on keeping all my systems completely up to date.  Some will boot certain kernel revs, others with seemingly identical hardware will not.

Comment: but 2 revisions in a row... I think I have some other problem with the system that prevents new Kernel from loading.